# Bloomberg Security Lookup Request

Tags: java, c++, api, blpapi

In the Bloomberg API Developer’s Guide it reads:

> The Security Lookup [...] request constructs a search based upon the "query" element's string value, as well as the additional filters that you set [...]. This unctionality can also be found on the Bloomberg Professional service using the **SECF < GO >** function.

This is a simple snippet querying for IBM (C++, while I am actually targeting Java):

```
Service secfService = session.getService("//blp/instruments");
Request request = secfService.createRequest("instrumentListRequest");
request.asElement().setElement("query", "IBM");
request.asElement().setElement("yellowKeyFilter", "YK_FILTER_CORP");
request.asElement().setElement("languageOverride", "LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE");
request.asElement().setElement("maxResults", 10);
sendRequest(request, session);
```

With the `SECF` function I can set many other filters, such as the exchange, the country of domicile (which are also mapped in the `FLDS` function screen).

When I pass `("exchCode", "US")`, I get an error.

> com.bloomberglp.blpapi.NotFoundException: Element: exchCode not found in: InstrumentListRequest

(I tried with `EXCH_CODE` too)

How can I pass `SECF` filters to the `request` object?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The documentation on this service is not very detailed - you should talk to Bloomberg directly and ask them for a list of filters that are available from the API.

Comment: There are more filters available with the curveListRequest, unfortunately, not available in the instrumentListRequest. Why can't Bloomberg make their API's more useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet of Python code that dumps the schema for the InstrumentListRequest.  Might be some language translation differences, but it's the same underlying API.
Sadly it doesn't look like you can formulate the query in the way you want to.

```
>>> print(instrreq.asElement().elementDefinition().toString())
ELEMENT InstrumentListRequest {
DESCRIPTION 
MIN VALUES 0
MAX VALUES 1
TYPE InstrumentListRequest (SEQUENCE) {
    DESCRIPTION Instrument list request
    ELEMENT query {
        DESCRIPTION String with keywords
        MIN VALUES 0
        MAX VALUES 1
        TYPE STRING
    }
    ELEMENT yellowKeyFilter {
        DESCRIPTION Yellow key filter
        MIN VALUES 0
        MAX VALUES 1
        TYPE YellowKeyFilter(ENUMERATION) {
            DESCRIPTION 
            YellowKeyFilter(STRING) {
                YK_FILTER_NONE
                YK_FILTER_CMDT
                YK_FILTER_EQTY
                YK_FILTER_MUNI
                YK_FILTER_PRFD
                YK_FILTER_CLNT
                YK_FILTER_MMKT
                YK_FILTER_GOVT
                YK_FILTER_CORP
                YK_FILTER_INDX
                YK_FILTER_CURR
                YK_FILTER_MTGE
            }
        }
    }
    ELEMENT languageOverride {
        DESCRIPTION Language override
        MIN VALUES 0
        MAX VALUES 1
        TYPE LanguageOverride(ENUMERATION) {
            DESCRIPTION 
            LanguageOverride(STRING) {
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE
                LANG_OVERRIDE_ENGLISH
                LANG_OVERRIDE_KANJI
                LANG_OVERRIDE_FRENCH
                LANG_OVERRIDE_GERMAN
                LANG_OVERRIDE_SPANISH
                LANG_OVERRIDE_PORTUGUESE
                LANG_OVERRIDE_ITALIAN
                LANG_OVERRIDE_CHINESE_TRAD
                LANG_OVERRIDE_KOREAN
                LANG_OVERRIDE_CHINESE_SIMP
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE_1
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE_2
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE_3
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE_4
                LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE_5
                LANG_OVERRIDE_RUSSIAN
            }
        }
    }
    ELEMENT maxResults {
        DESCRIPTION Number of results requested
        MIN VALUES 0
        MAX VALUES 1
        TYPE INT32
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Even the different YK_FILTER's are not documented in the blapi document. I was wondering how to do a currency YK until I found this.