# unable to call blpapi function (InstrumentsListRequest) using xbbg

Tags: python, bloomberg, quantitative-finance, blpapi

I am trying to call the example of blpapi using xbbg

```
from xbbg.core import conn, process
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import date

def allInstruments():  # Return all govts with the given ticker, matured or not
    req = process.create_request(service='//blp/instruments', request='instrumentListRequest')
    req.set('query', "Dhaka")
    req.set('maxResults', 10)

    def _process_instruments(msg):  # Process the response
            print(msg)
            pass

    conn.send_request(request=req)
    
    processed_elements_list = list(process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments))

    for i in processed_elements_list:
        print(i)

allInstruments()
```

it gives me following error but still i get the result

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\Examples.ipynb Cell 45 line 2
     18     for i in processed_elements_list:
     19         print(i)
---> 21 allGovts()

h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\Examples.ipynb Cell 45 line 1
     14 conn.send_request(request=req)
     16 # Process events and get the list of elements
---> 17 processed_elements_list = list(process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments))
     19 # Iterate over the processed elements
     20 for i in processed_elements_list:

File h:\tanjin-work\xbbg\xbbg\core\process.py:197, in rec_events(func, **kwargs)
    195 if ev.eventType() in responses:
    196     for msg in ev:
--> 197         for r in func(msg=msg, **kwargs):
    198             yield r
    199     if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

result snap

```
CID: {[ valueType=AUTOGEN classId=0 value=65 ]}
RequestId: 2838b8e0-83d5-4fb7-855f-d2122184f5c2
InstrumentListResponse = {
    results[] = {
        results = {
            security = "MBL BD<equity>"
            description = "Marico Bangladesh Ltd (Dhaka)"
        }
        results = {
            security = "BATBC BD<equity>"
            description = "British American Tobacco Bangladesh Co Ltd (Dhaka)"
        }
        results = {
            security = "DSEX<index>"
            description = "Bangladesh Dhaka Stock Exchange Broad Index"
        }
        results = {
            security = "BRAC BD<equity>"
            description = "BRAC Bank PLC (Dhaka)"
        }
        results = {
            security = "SQUARE BD<equity>"
            description = "Square Pharmaceuticals PLC (Dhaka)"
        } 
.....
```

it shows all the data where max value is not working

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code is not `yield`ing anything in the `_process_instruments` function, so the result cannot be iterated over.

Alternative code:

```
from xbbg.core import conn,process
import pandas as pd
    
def allSecurities(query,yellowKey, maxResults): 
    req = process.create_request(service='//blp/instruments',request='instrumentListRequest')
    req.set('query',query)

    if yellowKey is not None: req.set('yellowKeyFilter',yellowKey)

    req.set('languageOverride','LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE')
    req.set('maxResults',maxResults)
        
    def _process_instruments(msg): #Process the response
        for elt in msg.asElement().getElement('results').values():
            yield elt.getElementAsString('security'),elt.getElementAsString('description')
    
    conn.send_request(request=req)
    return process.rec_events(func=_process_instruments)

def allStocks(query,maxResults=1000):
    return pd.DataFrame(allSecurities(query,'YK_FILTER_EQTY',maxResults),
                        columns=['Security','Description'])

print(allStocks("Dhaka",10))
```

with the output:

```
              Security                                        Description
0    SQUARE BD<equity>                 Square Pharmaceuticals PLC (Dhaka)
1      GRAM BD<equity>                           GrameenPhone Ltd (Dhaka)
2      BRAC BD<equity>                              BRAC Bank PLC (Dhaka)
3    BXPHAR BD<equity>                Beximco Pharmaceuticals Ltd (Dhaka)
4    OLYMPI BD<equity>                     Olympic Industries Ltd (Dhaka)
5  TITASGAS BD<equity>  Titas Gas Transmission & Distribution Co Ltd (...
6      DBHF BD<equity>                            DBH Finance PLC (Dhaka)
7        PB BD<equity>                             Prime Bank PLC (Dhaka)
8      UPGO BD<equity>  United Power Generation and Distribution Co Lt...
9    ALARAB BD<equity>                  Al-Arafah Islami Bank PLC (Dhaka)
```

The `yellowKeyFilter` allows you to filter only the security types you want. Alternatives are `YK_FILTER_INDX`,`YK_FILTER_CORP` and others. If not set, you get all matches (I think).

The `//blp/instruments` service is a little fickle, and the Bloomberg documentation is quite thin. Eg, the `query` is not selecting by Ticker but seems to be matching on the `Description` field. An alternative is to use instrument searches saved by name in the Terminal (in the equivalent of the Excel `BSRCH()` function).

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected. can you provide me the documentation from where i can found such those reference you provided such that YK_FILTER_EQTY is available and YK_FILTER_INDX etc maybe others ?

Comment: From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049542/bloomberg-security-lookup-request. To cut a long story short, each API request type has a schema which can be queried (using the lower level blpapi).

Comment: That helps a lot its 8y old post impressive. do you have any reference or advice how can i find the curve ids. I was following this https://www.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/bloomberg.lookup.html#d126e41502 but looking forward for that

Comment: Because curveListRequest requires following to find any  ['countryCode', 'currencyCode', 'type', 'subtype', 'curveid', 'bbgid']

Comment: Maybe ask a new question on this? Give some detail on what you are trying achieve with examples. Generally I use `CVRF` on the Terminal to find the curve Ids I want.